# software to compare zip files

Tags: diff

I want to know any software which can compare zip files

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Please see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20080/archive-file-compare-diff-software/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [several tools](http://www.google.nl/search?q=compare+zip+files&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&redir_esc=&ei=dHDrTIq_KdHoOaHIlVU) available. Personally I like [UltraEdit - Ultra Compare](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultracompare/compare_zip_rar_and_jar_archives.html).